# $S_{n}$ is a submartingale, $\sup_{n\geq0}E[|S_{n}|] < \infty \Leftarrow \sup_{n\geq0}E[S_{n}^{+}] <\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$\sup_{n\geq0}E[|S_{n}|] < \infty \Leftarrow \sup_{n\geq0}E[S_{n}^{+}] <\infty$ is apparently true. The converse is easy to prove and thus it is an iff statement. I have tried a few different things (see comments) but a point in the right direction would certainly be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to clarify what your question is here? I assume you want a proof of the mentioned implication. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried working with stopped submartingales and martingale convergence theorems but neither route has led to an answer. Next thing I am thinking of is relating it to the supermartingale $-S_{n}$ and making inference from there.

Comment: And for the sake of clarity, I guess a pointer in the right direction is all this question is really asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the kind of things you've been trying, this is a lot simpler than you think.

Since $S_n$ is a submartingale, 
$$\mathbb{E}[S_n] = \mathbb{E}[S_n^+ - S_n^-] \geq \mathbb{E}[S_0].$$
Rearranging gives us that $\mathbb{E}[S_n^-] \leq \mathbb{E}[S_n^+] - \mathbb{E}[S_0]$ which will lead to the desired bound by writing $|S_n| = S_n^+ + S_n^-$.

Comment: Thank you, I really was overdoing it!